# Problems to deploy my angular app in node js server

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular6

I have a problem deploying my app in a google cloud server...

I start making  `npm build --prod` to create my dist folder, then i pass this folder to my back end folder just like i show u in the picture

[image]

When I start the nodejs server, I can connect locally with localhost: 8000, but when I try to access it from another device outside that network, it is impossible for me to make the connection, what Im doing wrong ... this is the code of my server server

```
   #!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('TestBoxprueba:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Socket.io
 */
var socket = require('socket.io');
/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port,'127.0.0.1');
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 *Socket setup.
 */
var io = socket(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
console.log('Conexion socket establecida')
});

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

pd: im using express to doing this.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you, but if you are running a server on a machine, you cannot access it outside the network.  You would have to contact your ISP for a public IP address and your router would have to be configured to allow the traffic.

Comment: is a virtual instance from google cloud service, i only can have access from a remote desktop

Comment: You'll still need to assign an IP address so that your VM can be reached externally. I've never used Google Cloud but I think this is a start: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

Lookup IP Address of windows in local LAN and call it with the port in another machine in LAN. If face issues then it must be due to permissions in local LAN.

I suggest you use tunnelling solutions like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

This will expose your localhost to the internet. For testing, I suggest you use this.